# Firefox Profile for Portable Firefox - Excel VBA in Selenium

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, vba

Hi I am using firefox potable version which works fine. However I am not able to set the profile as the profile directory is being ignored. Would if anyone has used this.

> Declarations as under

```
 Private assert As New assert
 Private driver As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
 Private elms As Selenium.WebElements
 Private elm As Selenium.WebElement
```

Portable Firefox Location. as per the help. I also tried to to put profile directory after set binary, but still the results are same.

```
 driver.SetProfile ("G:\Software - Portable\FirefoxPortable37\Data\profile")
 driver.SetBinary ("G:\Software -Portable\FirefoxPortable37\FirefoxPortable.exe")
```

> This runs the firefox portable version 37, but ignores the profile with extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of experiment I found that adding a true at the end works. So the code looks like

```
 driver.SetBinary ("X:\Path\FirefoxPortable37\Data\profile"),True
```